# Update Progress Bar Maximum after Task is Started

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am looking for an approach for updating the maximum value of a progress bar.  I would like to use a determine progress bar if that is the correct way to accomplish this.  Which I have setup below

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Progress Dialog", true);
progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 500);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
dialog.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, progressBar);
dialog.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JLabel("Progress..."));
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);           dialog.setSize(300, 75);
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
```

At this time I do not know what the maximum for the progress bar will be.  In the block below runner is an subclass of a SwingWorker.  It is not until after that process starts that I know what the maximum will be for the progress bar.

```
// run the report in its own thread
try {
    runner = ReportFactory.create(reportName, startDate, endDate);
    runner.addPropertyChangeListener(progressListener);
    runner.execute();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    logger.error(e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

I have tried this with and without the invoke later.

```
private class ProgressListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (runner.getProgress() == 0) {
//          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//              public void run() { 
            progressBar.setMaximum(runner.getMaximumProgressSize());

//              }
//          });
        }

        progressBar.setValue(runner.getProgress());
    }
}
```

To me, invokeLater will not work, because the task has not finished working.   I have spent the better part of a day trying to get this progress bar to work.   Any help or a change in direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Normalise your progress value.  That is, the `JProgressBar` is always 0-100, rather then sending the "actual" value of the job, normalise the value to a range of 0-100, ie `(amountDone / totalAmount) * 100d)`

Answer (score 0):

The comment above worked great!